# WPF Listbox item information

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

For each item in my listbox, I have a `Button` and a `TextBlock`. I can set my button to raise an event that removes an item from the ListBox, if I click on the TextBlock to highlight the item and then `Remove(myListBox.SelectedItem)`.

However, I'm looking for a way to identify which item in the ListBox a specific Remove-Button is attached to, so I can `RemoveAt(?)` when the event is raised.

Edit: Each of the buttons should remove the item on the line of that button without highlighting the line first. Therefore, using ListBox.SelectedItem is not a viable option :)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I'm just searching for the functionality, there's no problems with the code otherwise :)

Comment: That is *not* the point. The more information that you provide, the better the answers that you will receive.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the item using the `IndexOf` method:

```
YourCollection.RemoveAt(YourCollection.IndexOf(myListBox.SelectedItem));
```

Comment: I'm trying to get around the SelectedItem property, since the button should remove the item even if it hasn't been selected (yes, there's a button for every item in the listbox).

Comment: If you include important information like that in your questions, then you will get better answers and waste less time.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had made that clear in the first sentence. I'm thankful for the response anyhow!